# Combinations in Pandas Python (more than 2 unique)

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe where each row has a particular activity of a user:

```
 UserID     Purchased
  A          Laptop
  A          Food
  A          Car
  B          Laptop
  B          Food
  C          Food
  D          Car
```

Now I want to find all the unique combinations of purchased products and number of unique users against each combination. My data set has around 8 different products so doing it manually is very time consuming. I want end result to be something like:

```
Number of products   Products    Unique count of Users
       1              Food                1
       2              Car                 1
       2            Laptop,Food           1
       3            Car,Laptop,Food       1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# updated sample data
d = {'UserID': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'A', 3: 'B', 4: 'B', 5: 'C', 6: 'D', 7: 'C'},
 'Purchased': {0: 'Laptop',
  1: 'Food',
  2: 'Car',
  3: 'Laptop',
  4: 'Food',
  5: 'Food',
  6: 'Car',
  7: 'Laptop'}}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)


# groupby user id and combine the purchases to a tuple
new_df = df.groupby('UserID').agg(tuple)
# list comprehension to sort your grouped purchases
new_df['Purchased'] = [tuple(sorted(x)) for x in new_df['Purchased']]
# groupby purchases and get then count, which is the number of users for each purchases
final_df = new_df.reset_index().groupby('Purchased').agg('count').reset_index()
# get the len of purchased, which is the number of products in the tuple
final_df['num_of_prod'] = final_df['Purchased'].agg(len)
# rename the columns
final_df = final_df.rename(columns={'UserID': 'user_count'})

             Purchased  user_count  num_of_prod
0               (Car,)           1            1
1  (Car, Food, Laptop)           1            3
2       (Food, Laptop)           2            2
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. It still doesn't fulfill my requirement because if a person has bought laptop and car, that person shouldnt be coming in "laptop only" category. As per your solution, it is. would really appreciate if you can guide me with this bro. thanks.

Comment: @Hassaan, I assumed you wanted all combinations. Pleased update your sample data and expected output to reflect what you are looking for.

Comment: @Chris, I have updated the sample data and expected out. I do want all possible combinations but want the count of users for that particular combination only. In expected output, the first row shows 1 as unique count because only 1 user had 1 product only and that being "Food". In your solution above, that would've shown 3 as unique count after "Food"